# Difference in joined or splitted random slopes in mixed model (lme4 notation)

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interpretation, model-selection, random-effects-model

I would like to understand better the consequences of formula syntax choices in lme4 package.

Imagine I want to model outcome Y as a function of X1 and X2 = f(X1), with and without interaction, with a random slope at the Z level. f(X1) may be for example the log of X1. In my specific case X is Time and Z is Country. The intuition is that in some Country Z the effect of X1 is stronger while in other X2 is, so each country will have a mixture of two different functional forms of the effect of time. THe interaction allows for further changes in time since the effect is totally not stationary.

I'm struggling to understand the statistical and interpretational differences of the subsequent models.

Additive models:

1. ~ X1 + X2 + (X1 + X2 | Z)
2. ~ X1 + X2 + (X1 | Z) + (X2 | Z)
3. ~ X1 + X2 + (1 | Z) + (0 + X1 | Z) + (0 + X2 | Z)

The models 1 and 3 give similar results (but not identical) and fit well the observed data, while the 2 shows predictions that are above or below the data for some countries. I guess that this happens because it creates 2 random intercepts that shrink strongly the prediction average towards a global average?

Interaction models:

1. ~ X1 + X2 + (X1 * X2 | Z)
2. ~ X1 * X2 + (X1 * X2 | Z)
3. ~ X1 + X2 + (1 | Z) + (0 + X1 | Z) + (0 + X2 | Z) + (0 + X1:X2 | Z)
4. ~ X1 * X2 + (1 | Z) + (0 + X1 | Z) + (0 + X2 | Z) + (0 + X1:X2 | Z)

Model 3 has predictions that are very similar to the additive models while the others are all very influenced by changes in trends that happens later in time. But the similarity between the models between them and between the additive and the interaction models changes in every country and I cannot retrieve a robust pattern by intuition only without understanding the implication of the various notations.

I can add that the models with the unsplitted random effects have a lower BIC score and that model 1 of the interaction model has the lowest BIC score.

Comment: Interesting post!  I would have thought your additive models 1. and 3. would produce identical results - it's intriguing that they don't - I hope someone here can explain why.  For your interaction models, your models 2. and 3. don't make sense to me.  Don't you need to have X1:X2 represented in the model as a fixed effect in addition to having it represented as a random effect? That is, shouldn't your interaction model 1. Be specified as  ~ X1 + X2  + X1:X2 + (X1 * X2 | Z)  (which would make it equivalent to interaction model 2.)?

Comment: @Isabella Ghement just a quick comment regarding the additive models 1 and 3: they are not equivalent as in model 3 no parameters for the covariance between the random intercepts and random slopes are estimated.

Comment: @IsabellaGhement I thought the same about model 1 and 3 additive, but as statmerkur said no correlation between slope and interaction is estimated, but I'm not sure what practical effect would this have on predictions. For model 2 and 3 interaction, glmer automatically converts X1*X2 into X1 + X2 + X1:X2, at least for the fixed effect, not sure it does it also for the random slope.

Comment: ah sorry I misinterpreted. No, model 1 characteristic is that there is an only random interaction term with population mean zero and different effects in every country. The idea is that this term switches on only in countries which have some characteristics but is not there globally.

Comment: Please check Dr. Ben Bolker's insightful responses on this Twitter thread: https://twitter.com/isabellaghement/status/1238849981462671363?s=21.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, @statmerkur!

Comment: @IsabellaGhement thank you! checked the discussion. The fact that the correlation is being estimated, how does impact the estimated parameters and then the predictions? Does it add shrinkage on one parameter given another? I'm also trying to figure out what would happen for predictions, but probably it depends from the specific model

Comment: does (X1 * X2 | Z) even work? it makes theoretical sense but I don't think it's implemented ...

Comment: @Bakaburg:  So your interaction model 1 is of the form Y_ij = (beta0 + b_j) +  (beta1 + u_j)*X1 + (beta2 + v_j)*X2 + (beta3 + w_j) X1*X2 where beta3 is assumed to be known and equal to 0 and b_j is a random intercept, u_j is a random slope for X1, v_j is a random slope for X2, w_j is a random slope for the cross-product of X1 and X2?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement uhm yes, seems correct

Comment: @BenBolker it works, I can show some plots later. which models' predictions would you be interested more in? (putting all of them together would be a mess).

Comment: @BenBolker: If (X1*X2|Z) does not work, will (X1 + X2 + X1:X2|Z) work? Also, intuitively, if one assumes uncorrelated random slopes for X1 and X2 when they should be correlated, prediction intervals would be narrower than they should be since they would assume there is more information in the data than there actually is.  Conversely, if one assumes correlated random slopes for X1 and X2 when they should be uncorrelated, prediction intervals should be wider than they should be since they would assume there is less information in the data than there actually is. Is this intuition correct?

Comment: What does it mean "(X1*X2|Z) does not work"? I don't get any error (apart from convergence warning, but that is expected with so many parameters)

Comment: @Bakaburg:  Usually, when a parameter value is known in a model, we use an offset term to specify it. Something like: ~ X1 + X2 + offset(0*X1:X2) for the fixed effects portion of the model.  I haven't seen the specification you used before - curious if the offset specification produces the same results as what you have. (I'm not near a computer right now.)

Comment: Yes, (X1 + X2 + X1:X2|Z) works.  The problem is computational, not conceptual: lme4 doesn't know how to expand * in this context.  I will get back to this if I can.

Comment: @Bakaburg: I'm not sure it does what you think it's doing ...

Comment: I just checked, (X1*X2|Z) and (X1 + X2 + X1:X2|Z) gives identical results on model 2

Comment: @Bakaburg: Did you compare fixef(), ranef(), coef(), etc. for both specifications just to be sure?

Comment: yep, run identical() against them all and also varCorr and model.matrix

Comment: Huh. I'm surprised but would be happy to be wrong!